# Button IsEnabled state not updating based on CanExecute return value

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have a button in a Windows 8.1 'universal' app bound to a `RelayCommand` that is not updating to disabled as expected, based on the return value of `CanExecute()`.
 Implementation details are below, but basically, the `RelayCommand` is initialised to return false, changes to enabled as expected, but doesn't return to disabled as expected.

UI flow is once the user selects an item from a combobox (bound to a property), the `.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` is called and returns true, and the button updates to enabled as expected. A second combobox (now visible) is bound to another property, which when changed runs a method to set a validation property, which when changed calls `.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()`. This time, when I expect to see the button disabled, it isn't, despite `CanExecute()` returning false. Funnily enough, the delegate method that is the action doesn't run if the button is then clicked, but I need the button disabled, since the `click` method of the button is `Frame.GoBack()`

RelayCommand class:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action _execute;
    private readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public RelayCommand(Action execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute();
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute();
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        var handler = CanExecuteChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

CanExecute method:

```
private bool CanAcceptTransportProfile()
    {
        if (IsTPInEditMode == false) return false;
        if (SelectedTransport == null) return false;
        if (IsSubPropertiesValid == false) return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Initial property and change:

```
public Unit SelectedTransport
    {
        get { return _selectedTransport; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedTransport != value)
            {
                _selectedTransport = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedTransport");
                OnSelectedTransportChange();
            }
        }
    }

private void OnSelectedTransportChange()
    {
        switch (SelectedTransport == null)
        {
            case true:
                IsTransportSelected = false;
                IsUnitsPerTransportValid = true;
                IsSharingWithValid = true;
                IsNestingValid = true;
                break;
            case false:
                IsTransportSelected = true;
                ShowUnitsPerTransportSelector = IsAllowedToShareTransport ? false : true;
                break;
        }
        CommandAcceptTransportProfile.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
```

Second property change:

```
public int UnitsPerTransport
    {
        get { return _unitsPerTransport; }
        set
        {
            if (_unitsPerTransport != value)
            {
                _unitsPerTransport = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("UnitsPerTransport");
                OnUnitsPerTransportChange();
            }
        }
    }

private void OnUnitsPerTransportChange()
    {
        List<int> unitoptions = UnitHelper.UnitRangeFromSquadSize(this.SquadSize);
        if (!unitoptions.Contains(_unitsPerTransport))
        {
            foreach (int num in unitoptions)
            {
                if (_unitsPerTransport < num)
                {
                    if (num % _unitsPerTransport != 0)
                    { goto Invalid; }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (_unitsPerTransport % num != 0)
                    { goto Invalid; }
                }
            }
            goto Valid;
        }
        else
        { goto Valid; }

    Valid:
        IsUnitsPerTransportValid = true;
        IsSubPropertiesValid = (IsUnitsPerTransportValid && IsNestingValid && IsSharingWithValid && IsTotalUnitsRequiredValid) ? true : false;
    Invalid:
        IsUnitsPerTransportValid = false;
        IsSubPropertiesValid = false;
    }
```

`IsSubPropertiesValid` raises `CommandAcceptTransportProfile.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` when it changes. The `UnitHelper` is a static class and just returns a list of `ints`. the method then checks the selected int from the combobox and goes to valid/invalid accordingly. it is when this sets `IsSubPropertiesValid` to false I expect to see the button become disabled, and it isn't.

I have been using the `RelayCommand` in this fashion throughout my project and it has worked in every instance as expected, except this one, which has more complex validation/Onproperty change calls surrounding it, so I suspect it has something to do with that, but it is beyond my self taught knowledge to resolve.

Comment: Have you tried to implement *INotifyPropertyChanged* in RelayCommand?

Comment: @Romasz -  I get the idea behind the suggestion, but am unsure how to modify the class to do so. I don't think it is as simple as removing the `ReadOnly` modifiers and adding backed properties, as I would need to actually set the property somewhere... are you able to provide some guidance?

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement *INotifyPropertyChanged*, a sample can look like this:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotify
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, "CanExecute");
        }
    }
    #endregion
```